# rewrite or redirect to curent page in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

hello guys i want to ask if there possible to rewrite or redirect to current page url if we are change our link page by manual in link bar?

example :

our current link is `www.example.com/example/data-data/link-link`

than im change that current link in the link bar become :

`www.example.com/example/data-data/link-li`

than

if the link was changed will be

redirect to `www.example.com/example/data-data/link-link`

if it is possible please guide me how to do it

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to do, all you have to do is follow the steps

1. Change your `routes.php` file as following (Replace `404_override` with `Errors` controller's `index` method)

   ```
   $route['404_override'] = 'errors/index';
   ```
2. Now create a `Errors` controller with `index` method in your controllers directory with following code

   ```
   defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

   class Errors extends CI_Controller {

   public function index() {

       redirect($this->router->fetch_class());
    }

   }
   ```

Now when you will browse any wrong link it will redirect you to corresponding controller from where you mistype.

Comment: that way if that link was going to error page right?, how about it was not to going to error page? example `base_url/controller/controller_path/variable_pass` than i change the variable i thought it will not go to error page right?

Comment: if variable changed then still you may send to error page if the record not exist in Database by using `show_404()` function

Comment: i got message "The page isn’t redirecting properly"

Comment: you have to set `show_404()` function in your `data-data` controller when record not exist. Perhaps you use it in `Errors` controller this is why it causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible in codeigniter you only need to make route for this link after that you can redirect where ever you want.
In codeigniter version 3 :-

File is located in :- application\config\routes.php

make your route and give which controller you want to run.

```
$route['example/data-data/link-li'] = 'your controller name';
```